# JavaScript filter through array of objects with a nested array and check for variable match within nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter

I have an array of objects with one property being an array of values without keys and I am attempting to filter through and check for matching values within the nested array. Here is an example of one object:

```
[ 0:
    { fiber_phases: ["45", "46"],
      id: 1,
      label: "3200 to 3299 1 1/2 ST N",
      max_number: "3299",
      min_number: "3200",
      parsed_hash: "4028c7befc61ba4d07189f6ba99de35f",
      street: "1 1/2 ST N" 
    }
]
```

Here is my javascript code thus far:

```
return this.blocks
    .filter((block) => block.fiber_phases === fiberPhase)
    .map(({id, label, max_number, min_number, street, parsed_hash, fiber_phases}) => ({id: id, label: label, max_number: max_number, min_number: min_number, street: street, parsed_hash: parsed_hash, fiber_phases: fiber_phases}))
```

It's pretty clear that I'm not actually going into the nested array, but I haven't been able to access it.

Comment: `I am attempting to filter through and check for matching values within the nested array.` is definitely not clear.

Comment: I agree with @void, can you post an example of the input and desired output?

Comment: Instead of `block.fiber_phases === fiberPhase` did you intend to do `block.fiber_phases.includes(fiberPhase)`?

Comment: I'll rephrase. My goal is to filter through an array of objects (all 11,231 of them), which each have a nested array of `fiber_phases`, and check for matches based on one fiberPhase value (i.e. let fiberPhase = '46'). I then would like to return a new array of objects that match that value.

Comment: Instead of `id: id,` just do `id,`

Comment: As a side note, you might be much better off using a proper database for this kind of thing.

Comment: Hah. If only. The backend for this is such a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter your main array such that it only contains objects that have `fiberPhase` anywhere in their `fiber_phases` array, you'd use `filter` with [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) in the predicate:

```
return this.blocks.filter(block => block.fiber_phases.includes(fiberPhase));
```

`Array.prototype.includes` is *relatively* recent, but trivial to polyfill (see the link above). Or if you don't want to, `indexOf` will work:

```
return this.blocks.filter(block => block.fiber_phases.indexOf(fiberPhase) !== -1);
```

Note that that will return a new array which shares the objects with the original. If you wanted to *copy* them, you'd add

```
.map(entry => Object.assign({}, entry))
```

to it, or with some [Stage 4 syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) that will be in the ES2018 spec:

```
.map(entry => ({...entry}))
```

Either way, it's a shallow copy (the `fiber_phases` array will be shared).

Adjust as needed.

Comment: @MattLarson: FWIW, if you need to repeatedly filter the *same* array, and *if* you run into performance problems, it may be worth building a `fiberPhase`-to-array map once (with the attendant memory hit) which you can then reuse...

Comment: Interesting. I'm also attempting to returning objects that contain a value match in the nested array and no other values :/ So right now, `.filter((block) => block.fiber_phases.includes(fiberPhase))` will return results sets that match fiberPhase and ones that match other fiberPhases as well. If only there was an `.onlyIncludes()` hah

Comment: @MattLarson: Wouldn't that be `block => block.fiber_phases.length == 1 && block.fiber_phases[0] == fiberPhase` ? :-)

Comment: I think that'd work! I'm having another issue, so I'll check in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
return this.blocks
    .filter(block => block.fiber_phases.include(fiberPhase))
    .map(block => Object.assign({}, block));
```

Or with the more recent ECMAScript 2018 [spread syntax for object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals):

```
return this.blocks
    .filter(block => block.fiber_phases.include(fiberPhase))
    .map(block => ({...block}));
```